# are there books/articles on writing hand-written parser with learn-by-doing or incremental approach?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

Because of only curiosity, I'd like to write hand-written parser, I know there are many compiler-compilers though.

Ironically saying, since I'm new in this branch, I have no confidence to understand underlying theory and then apply theoretical knowledge to build parser and further full compiler.

So learning-by-doing approach might be helpful. Are there good books/articles/tutorials met my desire in above manner?

Comment: Yes, there are many, many books on that topic.

Comment: my question seems to be ambiguous. i want to know specific list of those books/aritlces/etc..i'm ready to hear your recommendation.

Comment: I suggest the llvm tutorial: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend, it teaches you how to write a who compiler in few lines, including a top down hand writing parser. But if you come across problems like calculating first sets or something, you have to read some more professional books.

Comment: The classic reference is probably good old Jack Crenshaw ? http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf